# Constructor(props) and super(props) VS constructor() and super() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I know that this question was asked many times, but it is still doesn't clear.
Many people just said:

> Pass props to constructor if you want to access `this.props` there

[one more example of the answer](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781)

Oficial doc says [Class components should always call the base constructor with props.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) , but if we do not pass `props` to `constructor`, we will still have `this.props` everywhere exept constructor.

Also from [react source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/52752446760dee0bc7232b4146f5a309ac57f065/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js#L23) we can see source code of the React.Component
`function ReactComponent(props, context) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
}`

But it is confuses me even more. 
`super()` should be called with two parametrs: `props` and `context` . But we invoked our super empty and still have access two `this.props`.
According to ECMA documentation `super()` invokes parent `constructor()` with parametrs passed to `super()` . But our `super()` is empty.

***So my questions are:***

1. Why official docs says:

> Class components should always call the base constructor with props.

2. How React set `props` to child component if `super()` and `constructor()` is empty?
3. Is it bug of feature of the React that props are accessible in child component without passing props to `super()` and `constructor()`?

Comment: A compromise: `constructor(...args) { super(...args); }`

Comment: Why are you viewing such outdated source code?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js: `createElement` adds `props` regardless if you use `super(props)`.

Comment: @ Li357 Thanks for the link to the new source code. So current React doc is wrong or what? There is no need to call `constructor` always with `props` ?

Comment: Sorry, but does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is an answer from Dan Abramov:**

> But if we do not pass `props` to `constructor`, we will still have
>   `this.props` everywhere except `constructor`.

Yes, React sets `this.props` anyway after the `constructor` runs. Still, it is confusing to have `this.props` work in some places and not others. Especially if both `constructor` and other methods call some shared method that reads `this.props`. So, to avoid any potential confusion, we recommend always calling `super(props)`.

> Also from source code of `Create Element` you can see that `createElement`
>   adds props regardless if you use `super(props)`

`createElement()` has no relation to this question. It creates an element, not an instance.

So, to get back to your question, technically it's only necessary if you plan to access `this.props` in the `constructor` or any method you call from `constructor`. However it's pretty confusing to have to remember this. You might know about it and not call `super(props)`, but the next person on your team will want to access `this.props` in a `constructor` and will be surprised it doesn't work. It's just easier to always specify it to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 0):

If no constructor is defined in the code for a react component you can assume it will be automatically bound behind the scenes, such as:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
```

Once you have explicitly defined a constructor you must remember to always put that code in otherwise it will be left out... you are basically just overriding a default method :)